# Writing cython for both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Tags: python, numpy, 64-bit, cython

I'm working on project with some cython modules, which contain function definitions like

```
def f(np.ndarray[int, ndim=1, mode='c'] x):
    _f(&x[0])

cdef _f(int* x):
    ...
```

I'm on a 64-bit machine, so then at run-time I get errors like the following when calling `f`:

```
ValueError: Item size of buffer (8 bytes) does not match size of 'int' (4 bytes)
```

The code can be "fixed" to run on my machine by changing to `long` integers:

```
def f(np.ndarray[long, ndim=1, mode='c'] x):
    _f(&x[0])

cdef _f(long* x):
    ...
```

The problem is that NumPy integer arrays are defaulting to `int32` on 32-bit and `int64` on 64-bit, which correspond to `int` and `long`, respectively, in c/cython. (Is that even correct?)

*So, what is the recommended or standard practice for writing cython that will work with both 32-bit and 64-bit?*

1. Should I check `platform.architecture` and put a `ctypedef` at the top of my .pyx file? Does putting a `ctypedef` inside an if-statement even work? Something like this:

   ```
   import platform
   bits, linkage = platform.architechure
   if bits == '64bit':
       ctypedef long myint_t
   elif bits == '32bit':
       ctypedef int myint_t

   def f(np.ndarray[myint_t, ndim=1, mode='c'] x):
        _f(x)

   cdef _f(long* x):
       ...
   ```
2. Should I leave the cython library alone force the input array to be 32-bit integers? Something like this:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import my_cython_library

   data = np.arange(10, dtype='int32')
   my_cython_library.f(data)
   ```
3. Am I missing something obvious in the cython build or compilation options?

I don't like (1) because then I have custom types all around just for basic integers, and I don't like (2) because then I'm using my hardware poorly and specify the type even when it should be obvious. So I'm hoping there is a good option (3).

Answer (score 1):

How about declaring a [fused type](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html), e.g.:

```
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef fused int_t:
    np.int32_t
    np.int64_t

cdef int_t my_func(int_t[:] A, int_t[:] B):
    ...
```

That way you can have a single statically typed Cython function which can operate on either 32 bit or 64 bit integers.

Comment: Exactly the sort of (easy) thing I'm hoping for! I will try it. I realize that `f` in my example is a wrapper to a pure c function declared `cdef _f(int* x)`. Hopefully the fused type will help me there as well. I will update my question to include this.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use `cdef _f(int_t* x)`?

Comment: No, that's what I'm going to do. Though, there is not much different between a fused type and the `ctypedef` that I suggested in (1). Why would I choose a fused type over a conditional ctypedef, or vice versa?

Comment: Well for one thing the fused type is more flexible, in that it would accept either type of integer regardless of what platform it was compiled on. Cython fused types are used [quite extensively in scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ctypedef+fused&type=Code) for this reason.

Comment: I finally got back to this, and it's not working. I get `Cannot coerce to a type that is not specialized` and `Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized`

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. Without seeing more of your code and the traceback I can't really diagnose the problem. It might be that Cython doesn't like you explicitly declaring the return type as a fused type - for example you might try `cdef _f(int_t* x)` rather than `cdef int_t _f(int_t* x)`.